# Jenkins clearcase UCM plugin polling from baselines of other streams when set to poll self / ANY promotion and use newest baseline

Tags: jenkins, clearcase-ucm

I am currently setting up a jenkins project using the clearcase UCM plugin with the intention to poll the latest baseline for a specific stream and a specific component and execute a script that builds the baseline.

The build is being successful however the baseline that is being pulled is the latest baseline for the given component for ANY stream on clearcase.

my clearcase projects looks like:

```
- projectA
 * Main integration Stream
     * streamA
         * ChildStreamA_streamA
         * ChildStreamB_streamB
         * ChildStreamC_streamC
     * streamB
     * streamC
- projectB
- projectC
```

Each of these streams across all projects have the same component names, for example `componentA` and `ComponentB`

I have setup the jenkins UCM project to for example use stream `ChildStreamA_streamA` and `ComponentA`, use newest baseline. Jenkins would poll the correct Component (`ComponentA`), however the stream seems to be irrelevant, as it polls from the latest baseline accross all streams in all projects.

For example if the baseline for:

- `ComponentA` on `ProjectB` -> `streamB` -> `ChildStreamB_streamB`

was made after the latest baseline on:

- `ComponentA` on `projectA` -> `streamA` -> `ChildStreamA_streamA`

Jenkins will poll the baseline from the `projectB`'s `ChildStreamB_streamB` even if the specified stream was `projectA`'s `ChildstreamA_streamA`

Any ideas why the plugin would behave this way?

Answer (score 1):

After debugging the issue I found that it seems that the clearcase UCM plugin was designed assuming that for a given job, the stream that is being pulled from remains constant.

Although the job would eventually pick up the baselines of the other stream, it would take the other stream having a new baseline in order for that to take effect.

If anyone runs into this issue, I would suggest to maintain the assigned stream for any given job and to expect odd behavior if the stream is switched on a job that has already been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know Jenkins enough, but from CC side, I believe it reacts exactly for what is being asked for. So check if it is something with recommended baselines, Or maybe shared components between projects.